# Noun 勢い used as an adverb?

Tags: adverbs, nouns

> **勢い**地面に背中を打ちつけ、彼は顔をしかめた。

According to dictionaries, 勢い is a noun for momentum, force. In this sentence, isn't it used like an adverb to say that he knocked him on the ground with force?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed an uncommon adverbial usage of 勢い, but it means something different from what you are thinking:

> #### [勢い](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%8B%A2%E3%81%84)
>
> <sub>Adverb</sub>
> 4. naturally; necessarily

> #### [勢い](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%8B%A2%E3%81%84/)
>
> [副］その時のなりゆきで。必然的に。

So what is the previous sentence? Does "naturally" make sense?

"Hit with force" would have been 勢いよく打ち付けた, 勢いをつけて打ち付けた, etc.

Comment: I did see that definition, but "naturally, necessarily" is a bit odd in the context. It still works, but I guess the translation is more "with the momentum" than "naturally"? That would make more sense.

Comment: @Simon The adverbial 勢い should be etymologically "because of such a momentum", so it tends to be used when there is a "momentum" (physically or psychologically). The go-to translation is "naturally", but I can't say if your case is exceptional without seeing the actual previous sentence.

Comment: I remember seeing a discussion somewhere (I think on this site) that some intensifiers like すごい can be used adverbially without conjugation, could this be an example of a similar phenomenon?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky 勢い is not an (i-)adjective, so I don't think that's related.